# python csv library I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-upload, file-io

i am encountering an 'I/O operation on closed file' problem when for looping each row in csv_reader.

This is my code:

```
logFile = request.FILES['logs']
array = []
with logFile as csv_file:
    field_names = ['hi', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello' ]
    delimiter = ','
    quote_character = '"'
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=field_names , delimiter = delimiter, quotechar = quote_character)
    count = 0
    for rows in csv_reader:
        if count == 0:
            print count
        else:
            print count
            array.append(rows)
        count += 1

return array
```

logFile is the actual csv file that has been uploaded by a user, not the path.

```
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in     get_response
  111. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vcap/app/BillingWebApp/views.py" in IndexView
  128. csv_list_dict = csv_getting_list_dict.Csv_Parser(logFile)
File "/home/vcap/app/BillingWebApp/csv_getting_list_dict.py" in Csv_Parser
  5. with logFile.open() as csv_file:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/uploadedfile.py" in open
  97. self.file.seek(0)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: I/O operation on closed file.
```

The error occurs in my code at:

```
    for rows in csv_reader:
```

and in the debugger it gets to this:

```
row = self.reader.next()
```

Comment: You should edit your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719691/csv-library-error-i-o-operation-on-closed-file) instead.

Comment: and that was only a guest account and i needed a real account

Comment: ok, I didn't pay attention to the username

Comment: okay well any ideas on a fix?

Comment: @will Try passing the logFile variable directly to the csv.DictReader as a first parameter

Comment: @will another idea is (if csv files are not big) load them into memory using StringIO and then passing it as a file to the csv.DictReader class

Answer (score 0):

The type of `LogFile` is:

```
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
```

for `with logFile as csv_file:` statement you need file object i.e. `<type 'file'>`.

You need to save `LogFile` into file and then open file again for next process.

Comment: how do i save it into file?

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes your csv files can be loaded into memory:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

log_file = request.FILES['logs']
log_file.seek(0)
log_file_content = log_file.read()
in_memory_log_file = StringIO(log_file_content)

array = []

field_names = ['hi', 'hi', 'hello', 'hello' ]
delimiter = ','
quote_character = '"'
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(in_memory_log_file, fieldnames=field_names , 
                            delimiter = delimiter, quotechar = quote_character)
count = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    if count == 0:
        print count
    else:
        print count
        array.append(row)
    count += 1

return array
```

Comment: @will Can you try log_file.seek(0) before the read()? I will edit the answer code.

Comment: that gives me another error: Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vcap/app/BillingWebApp/views.py" in IndexView
  128.         csv_list_dict = csv_getting_list_dict.Csv_Parser(logFile)
File "/home/vcap/app/BillingWebApp/csv_getting_list_dict.py" in Csv_Parser
  5.     log_file.seek(0)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: I see no reason why the file is closed, do you use it before? Do you pass it to a form and then validate it?

Comment: @avernet there is now a problem with seek(0)

Comment: well im the post is in a view and im then passing the file i got from the post into the method that is giving me these errors

Comment: So, I can assume you haven't touched the request.FILES['logs'] before. Which Django version are you using? Look at this [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22680)

Comment: i have not no. and django 1.6.6?

Comment: but the build pack is using 1.7 and i updated mine to 1.7 and the bug is now local aswell so is that a bug in django then?

Comment: Yep, it was a bug in Django 1.7-alpha, but seems to be solved now...(and looks like it worked in Django 1.6.6)

Comment: Can you try this code at the beginning of the view code and let me know of the results?

Comment: yep exactly the same but at least i know where the error is now :) i have reverted to 1.6.6 for both the build pack and my local :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the file first. You might want to try something like that:

```
data = [row for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file.read(), fieldnames=field_names,
           delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quote_character)]
```